# Why are my string variables not being pushed in my stacks?

Tags: java, regex, stack

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pemdas {

public static double Express(String str)
{
    Stack<Double> num = new Stack<Double>();
    Stack<String> op = new Stack<String>();
    String number = "[0-9]*"; // any digit from 0-9


    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str.substring(i,i+1).equals(number))            
            num.push(Double.parseDouble(str.substring(i, i+1)));

        else if (str.substring(i, i+1).equals("+"))         
            op.push(str.substring(i, i +1));

        System.out.println(str);
    }

    double n = num.pop();
    if (op.pop().equals("+"))
        n = n + num.pop();


    return n;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    System.out.print("Enter an Expression: ");
    String ex = StdIn.readString(); // This is where I enter my string input
    System.out.println(Express(ex));

}

}
```

Let's say that I have an String variable of "5 + 5" as my input. In the for loop, the 5 is supposed to be pushed into the num stack, but I keep getting an ESE and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `equals()` when you want to match against a regex. `equals()` is for comparing literal strings. You likely want [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29):

```
if (str.substring(i,i+1).matches(number))
    num.push(Double.parseDouble(str.substring(i, i+1)));
```

---

In fact, you don't need a regex at all here. You can simplify your loop by doing something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    char c = str.charAt(i);

    if (Character.isDigit(c))            
        num.push((double) (c - '0'));

    else if (c == '+')         
        op.push("+");

    System.out.println(str);
}
```

---

Finally, please follow Java's naming conventions and call your method `express()` instead of `Express()`.

Comment: Does the '+' count as a literal string, or is it included in the regex? I tried the same thing with my op stack, but that is empty as well.

Comment: @igknighton Everything you pass as an argument to `equals()` is treated as a literal string.

Comment: Ok, my op stack is still considered empty. Is it because of the space between the 5s and the +?

Comment: @igknighton I just tried it and it worked fine, producing the correct output `10.0`.

Comment: Including the spaces? It works with "5+5", but I can't get it to work with "5 + 5". I greatly appreciate your help by the way.

Comment: @igknighton No problem, glad I could help. Yes, it's working with `"5 + 5"` (including the spaces). Just replace your current loop with what's above.

Comment: Ok, the StdIn Class I was using couldn't read the "5 + 5" input for some reason, so I ended up using something else. Thanks!